# Check if next element is the last element in the STL List

Tags: c++, stl

I've been trying many solutions. But can't figure out how to do this:

```
for (current = l.begin();current != l.end();current++)
{
    next = ++current;
     if(next != l.end())
            output << (*current)  << ", ";
     else
            output << (*current);
}
```

I'm trying to print the list and eliminate the last comma:

```
{1,3,4,5,}
There --^
```

Please advise.

Comment: Bartozs' answer is spot on. also, notice that by doing `next = ++current`, you're actually incrementing the iterator twice during one iteration of the loop, which should skip every odd-indexed element in your list. i'm assuming this is not something you'd want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest fix for your code would be:

```
for (current = l.begin();current != l.end();)
{
    output << (*current);

    if (++current != l.end())
        output << ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about doing it a different way...

```
if(!l.empty())
{
    copy(l.begin(), prev(l.end()), ostream_iterator<T>(output, ", "));
    output << l.back();
}
```

There are no conditions in the loop (the `std::copy` loops) so this is more optimal too.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently. Assuming that collections have usually more than one element, I would go with this:

```
        auto start = c.begin();
        auto last = c.end();

        if (start != last)
            output << *start++;

        for (; start != last; ++start)
            output << "," << *start;
```

Put all of this into a template function to get a reusable piece of code:

```
    //! Join a list of items into a string.
    template <typename Iterator>
    inline
    void
    join (std::ostream & output, Iterator start, Iterator last, std::string const & sep)
    {
        if (start != last)
            output << *start++;

        for (; start != last; ++start)
            output << sep << *start;
    }
```

Comment: FYI this is virtually the same as my answer... except with a lot more code. And btw the for loop could/should be in the `if(start != last)` as well (as the one in my answer is...)